# Swift - pop up view, date picker?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've googled for hours and have tried a handful of tutorials, but haven't been able to get this working:

I have a TableView, and I want to make it so pressing on a cell presents a popup that has a date picker.

I have my custom viewcontroller with the date picker presenting (popping up from the bottom), but it takes up the entire screen. Thoughts? I found one mention of this exact issue while googling but the solution didn't work.

Comment: You mean takes up the full width of the screen? The pickers do that. You can modify the width a little but not much. You might just consider sliding/segue to another screen although the UI Interface guidelines discourage going to a new screen to answer a date picker, but they in the end leave that up to the developer.  You could also consider a text based data entry.  Even a text field that has all kinds of validation checks, but that isn't easily Internationalizable.  If you mean it occupies all the vertical space then you need to constrain and or fix the constraints on the picker view.

Comment: Sorry - I mean the view pops up from the bottom, but it takes up the entire height of the screen (as well as width, but I want it to be the width of the screen).

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Is it programmatically created or through Interface Builder? Have you added the vertical constraints? Are you familiar with autolayout and constraint creation? If not, you really need to learn it. Not just so you can tear your hair out, but because it's a very intelligent mechanism that works pretty nicely when you get used to it.

Comment: Admittedly, very new to Swift/XCode. Built through Interface Builder. I'm using 'reset to suggested constraints', which sometimes doesn't work very well and I have to do it manually, but this time around it seems to be working. Unless it's the reason this setup isn't working...

Comment: I have never had much use with reset to suggested constraints because it usually doesn't know what you have in mind for the appearance, so forget that. Just systematically and intelligently add constraints until you get what you want. At first it's confusing because you can hardly believe how sensibly constraints work.  But fortunately you can anticipate what's wrong with constraints if you add them very methodically.

Comment: I checked out some tutorials on constraints. A little clearer now. Thank you for the suggestion! Hopefully my current solution will work once I put the correct constraint in. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to overlay a subview (object of UIView) (with a date picker and a done button) on top of your tableview. Then use .hidden feature of the subview to hide/show the view. The following is an example of the tableviewcontroller. When setting up the storyboard make sure that the subview has the layout constraints so the date picker is positioned properly. I used the "resolve auto layout issues" and it worked good. Unless you do special processing the subview will get positioned at the bottom of the rows. If you have a lot of rows the aubview will get clipped or hidden completely. So it is better to position the subview at the relative to the bottom of the page in your auto layout.

Here is a simple example that worked well for me. In viewDidLoad the subview is hidden. When you click on any row it will show the subview and the date picker. When you press done it will hide the subview again.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func doneButton(sender: UIButton) {
        // process the date using datePickerOutlet properties
        subView.hidden = true // hide the subview and its components
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var subView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePickerOutlet: UIDatePicker!
    @IBAction func datePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        subView.hidden = true // hide the subview and its components
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("\(indexPath.row)")
        subView.hidden = false // show the subview and its components
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, put it in a UIAlertView().  At least it will be centered. It's going to be tough to combine a table and a picker on a small screen, like let's say a 4S.

Comment: I've considered this... thing is, the way it's working right now, if I could just get the view to pop up to enough height to show the contents of that view, then it would work fine. Attached a photoshopped pic to show what I mean... http://imgur.com/Xb2Renm

Comment: Yep, exactly. Width size of the screen, height just enough to show the content of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get{
        // Checks if it is currently presenting
        if presentingViewController != nil {
            return (datePicker.sizeThatFits(presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size))
        }
        return super.preferredContentSize
    }
    set{ super.preferredContentSize = newValue }
}
```

This code goes under the View controller for the popup.
Basically what it does is to set the width of the popup to the minimum size required for the date picker.

Got it from the iTunes U tutorial by Paul Hegarty